# IE8 Web Font Bug

Tags: internet-explorer-8, fonts

I've got this weird problem happening with a site I'm currently working on. When you load the page, everything looks fine. It's only until you hover ANY part of the page that the some of the fonts shift, almost as if the letter-spacing contracts.

It's really hard to explain, but to see what I'm talking about have a look at this page in IE8, and keep an eye on the navigation and page title.

[Site Link](http://zakopanerentals.com/raph/apartments.html)

The problem started occurring when I added the Selectivizr.js to the site, and when I take Selectivizr js away it works fine.

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flash of unstyled content in IE with @font-face](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053152/flash-of-unstyled-content-in-ie-with-font-face)