# Flash of default font before @fontface shows in IE

Tags: css, ajax, fonts

What's the best way to stop IE displaying the default font while it's loading the @font-face webfont? The page is loaded with ajax and the css file is loaded in the head. This issue can be viewed at http://www.peterharveyco.com.au/ and then clicking on one of the scrolling projects. From what I've read, I'm loading the font correctly to avoid such a problem. It just loads whatever I set as the backup font until its ready. Is the only solution to set a close backup font? I'm ok with nothing being there until its ready if this is possible...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CSS file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStdBdCnNo.20';
    src: url('tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.eot');
    src: url('tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('tradegothicltstd-bdcn20-webfont.svg#TradeGothicLTStdBdCnNo.20') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: I do believe this happens when you have multiple style sheets that have font-family rules. It uses whatever loads first until the other stylesheet (that overrides it) finishes downloading. I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: I'll check that out - I do have multiple stylesheets there which is probably not optimal anyway... although I am loading the @fontface stylesheet first

Comment: I think I have found a suitable solution/work-around for my particular situation. The font was not being used on the home page. I added an h1 as the heading of the page (it needed it anyway) and used the -3000px margin to hide it off the page.
The obvious problem with this is if the user goes directly to the project page... But then I've just determined that the images in the slider aren't showing in IE when you go directly to the page anyway (e.g. http://www.peterharveyco.com.au/projects/austereo-perth - perhaps the subject of another question if I can't work that one out).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flash of unstyled content in IE with @font-face](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053152/flash-of-unstyled-content-in-ie-with-font-face)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Google's [WebFont loader](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader) to specify your @font-face fonts as a custom font. Looks like you can stick the @font-face rules in a style sheet on their own and then point the loader at this style sheet. You can then use the `.wf-loading` class to set the elements that have the custom @font-face fonts to be `visibility:hidden` so that the default font is not shown. Then use `.wf-active` class to set `visibility:visible` to show the @font-face fonts

Comment: I haven't confirmed this (my work-around is enough for me to carry on with something else) but it sounds like a solid plan. Thanks.